# AVPlayer seekToTime never completes

Tags: ios, objective-c, video-streaming, avplayer

I am using `AVPlayer` to stream video remotely. Whenever I scrub and use seekToTime it works, and the video plays from the location, however if I do this enough times sequentially then the completion handler of `seekToTime` never returns with *"finished == YES"* and is stuck.

Also, when profiling the connections it shows that the buffer never loads again even if `seekToTime` is called again after that. I can drag the scrubber to the beginning and playback will resume however it is not buffering anymore so it will get stuck in a *"buffering"* state once the buffer runs out but no buffer will be downloading.

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the content distribution network. The streaming url was expiring and then would no longer stream to the player

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem for a long time, but also noticed that even if the seek never completed, I would quickly get a current playback position update (via the block passed to [`addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:queue:usingBlock:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer/1385829-addperiodictimeobserverforinterv?language=objc)) that matched the target seek.

It appears, though, that I was doing some things in the wrong order when initializing the player with an item. I would set an item, and when the player's status became `AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay` I would begin the seek, and it would never complete. But if I don't begin the seek until the *current player item* status is `AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay`, everything works great.